# Apache2 configuration issue - Avoid file accessing without extension

Tags: apache2, apache2.4

I'm developing a website and having development environment as Ubuntu 14.04, PHP 5.5.9, Apache 2.4.7. My issue is if some want accessing a file like `http://domain.com/robots`(without extension) then I should avoid but I've to allow if some tries to access `http://domain.com/robots.txt`(with extension).

Now in both ways I'm able to access files, I want to avoid this when user haven't given extension of the file using `.htaccess` or apache configuration file.

My previous environment was Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.10 at the time with default Apache configuration it was working as expected but after upgrade its not working as expected and due lack of knowledge on Apache configuration I'm unable to pick those lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following line in `.htaccess`

```
Options -Multiviews
```